# Cannot call method `start_tls` when using Net::SMTP

Tags: ruby, smtp

I have the following code:

```
require 'net/smtp'

#This method prints the method "starttls"
p Net::SMTP.instance_methods

#And here I get an error of unknown method
Net::SMTP.starttls

Net::SMTP.start('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'mypassword') do |smtp|
smtp.open_message_stream('from@example.com', ['to@example.com']) do |f|
  f.puts 'From: from@example.com'
  f.puts 'To: to@example.com'
  f.puts 'Subject: My Subject!'
  f.puts 'Test subject.'
end
```

After showing that the method starttls is available in the list of instance methods of Net::SMTP.instance_methods I get the following error:

```
["starttls", "ready", "enable_starttls", "ssl?", "open_timeout", "capable_cram_md5_auth?", "tls?", "capable_plain_auth?", "data", "inspect", "disable_starttls", "rcptto", "starttls_auto?", "mailfrom", "open_timeout=", "capable_auth_types", "auth_cram_md5", "authenticate", "quit", "send_message", "rcptto_list", "set_debug_output", "esmtp=", "starttls?", "esmtp", "auth_plain", "debug_output=", "starttls_always?", "auth_login", "started?", "read_timeout", "capable_starttls?", "enable_tls", "finish", "open_message_stream", "enable_starttls_auto", "send_mail", "start", "address", "port", "sendmail", "esmtp?", "disable_tls", "helo", "read_timeout=", "disable_ssl", "capable_login_auth?", "ehlo", "enable_ssl", "handle_different_imports", "include_class", "java_kind_of?", "java_signature", "methods", "freeze", "extend", "==", "nil?", "object_id", "method", "tainted?", "is_a?", "instance_variable_get", "instance_variable_defined?", "instance_variable_set", "hash", "display", "send", "private_methods", "enum_for", "equal?", "com", "to_java", "type", "instance_of?", "id", "taint", "class", "java_annotation", "instance_variables", "to_s", "org", "to_a", "__send__", "=~", "protected_methods", "__id__", "java_implements", "tap", "frozen?", "java", "respond_to?", "instance_eval", "===", "java_package", "untaint", "clone", "java_name", "to_enum", "singleton_methods", "eql?", "instance_exec", "dup", "kind_of?", "java_require", "javax", "public_methods"]

NoMethodError: undefined method `starttls' for Net::SMTP:Class
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you are trying to call "starttls" as a static method and not instance method.
Please first define a new SMTP client and then call its "starttls" method.

```
smtp_client = Net::SMTP.new('address')
smtp_client.starttls
```